# converting file from .wsdl to .asmx

Tags: asp.net

I have a file with .wsdl and i want .asmx file from that,Is there any way of converting file from .wsdl to .asmx .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio itself or use the wsdl command line tool that comes with it like this:

```
wsdl /serverInterface path/to/test.wsdl
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of converting wsdl file to asmx... What exactly you need either you want to consume it or you want to host the service? If you want to consume it just add the webreference and consume it through your aspx.cs file.